# Non-blocking UDP server in Python game?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, twisted, pygame

I'm making an action game in Python. It has to support at least 2 players playing together over the Internet. I've chosen UDP since it seems to be the natural choice for low-latency games. I'm going with a client-server model and I want one player to host the game. This means one player is both hosting the game (server) and running the game (client) at the same time.

Should I be using threads for this or is there another approach? The problem is that the Python documentation says to use serve_forever but I need a non-blocking solution, ideally something I can just call every game loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network Support for Pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250739/network-support-for-pygame)

Answer (score 3):

I assume, by your reference to "the Python documentation says to use serve_forever" you are planning to use SocketServer. The module implements synchronous (forking or threading) servers, and you seem to be looking for asynchronous solutions.

For async, non-blocking solutions you might take a look to twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ (specifically twisted.internet).

Or, it you need something very specific and don't mind writing an event loop, just use poll or select for sockets and other resources...

Answer (score 2):

UDP is not the "natural choice".  It's an optimization for a specific type of problem (packet loss) for a specific type of data (typically position/velocity data).

You should stick with TCP until you can demonstrate that your game has a problem with it.

To integrate non-blocking networking into a game in Python, take a look at the approach taken by [Game](https://launchpad.net/game), which invokes the PyGame mainloop from Twisted.  This will work equally well with TCP, UDP, or any other protocol that uses sockets.